# Xcode MagicalRecord avoid WAL files generation

Tags: xcode, sqlite, magicalrecord, ios7.1

I'm building my first App with Magical Record and I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid the generation of the three files (dbname, dbname-shm, dbname-wal) for my model and proceed with the generation of a single file (dbname.sqlite).

I don't know where to set this string in MR files:

```
@{NSSQLitePragmasOption: @{@"journal_mode": @"delete"}}
if (![coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:url options:@{NSSQLitePragmasOption: @{@"journal_mode": @"delete"}, NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES} error:&error]) {
    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] presentError:error];
    return nil;
}
```

I looked into NSPersistentStoreCoordinator+MagicalRecord.m with no results.

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, you can do everything the plain old core data way and use the default add persistent store method on the persistent store coordinator.

Comment: If I weren't able to avoid the cration of the three files what could I use to browse the database and check what there is inside?

Comment: Base.app is handy, and a tool I use daily to examine sqlite core data stores